# Colum is created but no values are posted

Tags: php, forms

I got this problem where my form only posts the column itself without any values. I've tried figuring out what the problem is without any luck. My thought is that its a problem with the variables but don't really know what's wrong.

Edit: I have solved the issue, it was not the PDO/php. It simply was that the html form was structured wrong with multiple forms which is fixed now. Thanks for all the help!

```
<?php
include ('../functions.php');
$forare = $_POST ['forare'];
$sjukskot = $_POST ['sjukskot'];
$rakel = $_POST ['rakel'];
$id = $_POST ['id'];
$tillstand = $_POST ['tillstand'];
$medvet = $_POST ['medvet'];
$andn = $_POST ['andn'];
$puls = $_POST ['puls'];
$blodt = $_POST ['blodt'];
$triage = $_POST ['triage'];
$medvet2 = $_POST ['medvet2'];
$andn2 = $_POST ['andn2'];
$puls2 = $_POST ['puls2'];
$blodt2 = $_POST ['blodt2'];
$triage2 = $_POST ['triage2'];
$behandling = $_POST ['behandling'];
$anamnes = $_POST ['anamnes'];

require_once('../configs/dbconfigpdo.php');

try{

$query = "INSERT INTO ambjournal (forare, sjukskot, rakel, id, tillstand, medvet, andn, puls, blodt, triage, medvet2, andn2, puls2, blodt2, triage2, behandling, anamnes) VALUES ('$forare', '$sjukskot', '$rakel', '$id', '$tillstand', '$medvet', '$andn', '$puls', '$blodt', '$triage', '$medvet2', '$andn2', '$puls2', '$blodt2', '$triage2', '$behandling', '$anamnes');";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindparam(":forare",$forare);
$stmt->bindparam(":sjukskot",$sjukskot);
$stmt->bindparam(":rakel",$rakel);
$stmt->bindparam(":id",$id);
$stmt->bindparam(":tillstand",$tillstand);
$stmt->bindparam(":medvet",$medvet);
$stmt->bindparam(":andn",$andn);
$stmt->bindparam(":puls",$puls);
$stmt->bindparam(":blodt",$blodt);
$stmt->bindparam(":triage",$triage);
$stmt->bindparam(":medvet2",$medvet2);
$stmt->bindparam(":andn2",$andn2);
$stmt->bindparam(":puls2",$puls2);
$stmt->bindparam(":blodt2",$blodt2);
$stmt->bindparam(":triage2",$triage2);
$stmt->bindparam(":behandling",$behandling);
$stmt->bindparam(":anamnes",$anamnes);
$stmt->execute();

header ('Location: ../ambulansjournal.php');
exit();
}

catch(PDOException $exception){

die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());

}
?>
```

Comment: This is not how you use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0):

In the second section of your query, I mean "value" section, you should declare the parameters that begin with ":" like ":forare".

Your query should be :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ambjournal (forare, sjukskot, rakel, id, tillstand, medvet, andn, puls, blodt, triage, medvet2, andn2, puls2, blodt2, triage2, behandling, anamnes) VALUES (':forare', ':sjukskot', ':rakel', ':id', ':tillstand', ':medvet', ':andn', ':puls', ':blodt', ':triage', ':medvet2', ':andn2', ':puls2', ':blodt2', ':triage2', ':behandling', ':anamnes');";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes in this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ambjournal (forare, sjukskot, rakel, id, tillstand, medvet, andn, puls, blodt, triage, medvet2, andn2, puls2, blodt2, triage2, behandling, anamnes) VALUES ('$forare', '$sjukskot', '$rakel', '$id', '$tillstand', '$medvet', '$andn', '$puls', '$blodt', '$triage', '$medvet2', '$andn2', '$puls2', '$blodt2', '$triage2', '$behandling', '$anamnes');";
```

and replace it with this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ambjournal (forare, sjukskot, rakel, id, tillstand, medvet, andn, puls, blodt, triage, medvet2, andn2, puls2, blodt2, triage2, behandling, anamnes) VALUES (:forare, :sjukskot, :rakel, :id, :tillstand, :medvet, :andn, :puls, :blodt, :triage, :medvet2, :andn2, :puls2, :blodt2, :triage2, :behandling, :anamnes);";
```

Update:

You can also do like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ambjournal (forare, sjukskot, rakel, id, tillstand, medvet, andn, puls, blodt, triage, medvet2, andn2, puls2, blodt2, triage2, behandling, anamnes) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindparam(1,$forare);
$stmt->bindparam(2,$sjukskot);
$stmt->bindparam(3,$rakel);
$stmt->bindparam(4,$id);
$stmt->bindparam(5,$tillstand);
$stmt->bindparam(6,$medvet);
$stmt->bindparam(7,$andn);
$stmt->bindparam(8,$puls);
$stmt->bindparam(9,$blodt);
$stmt->bindparam(10,$triage);
$stmt->bindparam(11,$medvet2);
$stmt->bindparam(12,$andn2);
$stmt->bindparam(13,$puls2);
$stmt->bindparam(14,$blodt2);
$stmt->bindparam(15,$triage2);
$stmt->bindparam(16,$behandling);
$stmt->bindparam(17,$anamnes);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I've tried that but then nothing posts, no column is created.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used PDO, but I remember that it was easier for me to add all the information in an array and then bind parameters by preparing the query with the same array. You could do something like this (tidying SQL and array for easier reading):

```php
$post_info = array(
    'forare' => $_POST['forare'],
    'sjukskot' => $_POST['sjukskot'],
    'rakel' => $_POST['rakel'],
    'id' => $_POST['id'],
    'tillstand' => $_POST['tillstand'],
    'medvet' => $_POST['medvet'],
    'andn' => $_POST['andn'],
    'puls' => $_POST['puls'],
    'blodt' => $_POST['blodt'],
    'triage' => $_POST['triage'],
    'medvet2' => $_POST['medvet2'],
    'andn2' => $_POST['andn2'],
    'puls2' => $_POST['puls2'],
    'blodt2' => $_POST['blodt2'],
    'triage2' => $_POST['triage2'],
    'behandling' => $_POST['behandling'],
    'anamnes' => $_POST['anamnes']
);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO ambjournal
    (forare,
    sjukskot,
    rakel,
    id,
    tillstand,
    medvet,
    andn,
    puls,
    blodt,
    triage,
    medvet2,
    andn2,
    puls2,
    blodt2,
    triage2,
    behandling,
    anamnes
)
VALUES
(
    :forare, 
    :sjukskot,
    :rakel,
    :id,
    :tillstand, 
    :medvet, 
    :andn, 
    :puls,
    :blodt,
    :triage,
    :medvet2,
    :andn2, 
    :puls2, 
    :blodt2, 
    :triage2, 
    :behandling,
    :anamnes
)';

// Once you get this done, the next thing you do is prepare it and execute it with the array

$insert_query = $db->prepare($sql);

$insert_query->execute($post_info);
```

This must work, if it doesn't you probably have some data related issue. Either incorrect data type, data size or missing information.